# Is there a way to play mp3s in Qt 4.5?

Tags: qt4, audio, mp3

Is there a way to play mp3s in Qt 4.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phonon library from KDE has been included already in 4.4 release of QT.

I think there's even some sample code that ships with qt that shows how to utilize phonon to play mp3 files (and more).

Documentation here: http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/phonon-module.html

Phonon homepage: http://phonon.kde.org/

Comment: url for documentation added.  QT ships with phonon (enabled/disabled at build-time) so the examples can be viewed on your local machine if you have the source distribution.

Comment: great, I'm dropping my answer -- incorrect even though it quoted trolltech's docs verbatim!-)  Tx, this will be useful.

Answer (score 8):

example from Qt Assistant

QT += phonon

```
 Phonon::MediaObject *music =
     Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory,
                          Phonon::MediaSource("/path/mysong.mp3"));
 music->play();
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Don't forget to add #include <Phonon/MediaObject>